# Azure Policy - Target Specific Entry in Array

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I need to enable Network Policy (Route Table) for private endpoints in Azure. I've got a working Azure policy (shown below for reference), however this targets all subnets. Whilst this isn't *really* an issue (as the setting only applies to private endpoints anyway), I'd prefer to be more targeted, just to prevent confusion and in case any future weird bugs.

What I'm looking to do is only perform the modification ONLY on subnets with a specific name (e.g. snet-plink) - is this possible? I've had a bit of a play around and reviewed the docs, but I've not been able to achieve this yet.

Current working (broad) policy shown below:

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].privateEndpointNetworkPolicies",
        "notIn": [
            "RouteTableEnabled",
            "Enabled"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "modify",
        "details": {
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4d97b98b-1d4f-4787-a291-c67834d212e7"
          ],
          "operations": [
            {
              "operation": "addOrReplace",
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].privateEndpointNetworkPolicies",
              "value": "RouteTableEnabled"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "parameters": {}
  }
```

I've looked to see if there is a selector option for the array (like you have with jmespath) but this doesn't seem to exist with Azure policy. I've also explored count as an option, but again I don't think this will help me unfortunately with the modify effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since had chance to spend some time playing with this and have come up with an approach that works.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
        },
        {
          "field": "name",
          "equals": "snet-plink"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/privateEndpointNetworkPolicies",
          "equals": "Disabled"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4d97b98b-1d4f-4787-a291-c67834d212e7"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/privateEndpointNetworkPolicies",
            "value": "RouteTableEnabled"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking to do is only perform the modification ONLY on subnets with a specific name (e.g. snet-plink) - is this possible?

Here is the updated policy, it will enable the `Private Endpoint NetworkPolicies` property for the **subnet-name**, if it is not already set to **Enabled**.

In this policy, if the subnet equals `subnet-name` and the private endpoint network policy is not enabled in the same subnet, the policy will enable the route table policy in subnet.

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].name",
          "equals": "snet-plink"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].privateEndpointNetworkPolicies",
          "notIn": [
            "RouteTableEnabled",
            "Enabled"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4d97b98b-1d4f-4787-a291-c67834d212e7"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].privateEndpointNetworkPolicies",
            "value": "RouteTableEnabled"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Assign the policy to required scope and make sure to select a **remediation task** and a **managed identity** while policy assignment for enabling private endpoint  network policy in subnet.

[image]

Policy is created with **Remediation task** and a **Managed Identity** as below.

[image]

Once assigned, the policy will audit the subnets. If the private endpoint network policy is not enabled in a subnet, it will initiate the enabling process using a remediation task.

[image]

Reference: [AZURE POLICY TO ENABLE NETWORK POLICIES FOR PRIVATE ENDPOINTS](https://www.cloudcorner.gr/microsoft/azure/azure-policy-to-enable-network-policies-for-private-endpoints/) by  `Pantelis Apostolidis`

Comment: That was where my mind originally went, unfortunately that approach doesn't work - I've already tested it.

It doesn't actually seem to work at all for some reason, but even if it did the modify operation still applies to /subnets[*], so logically in my head the logic would be "if any of the subnets have no policies AND there is a subnet called snet-plink, then apply the modification to all subnets".